# Janus GridEx with DataSet Bound Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, janus

I have a strange issue with Janus GridEx.

The grid is bound  to DataSet containing 1 table, which is displayed on screen correctly. However, whenever I make changes to grid, they are not reflected in my DataSet.

This is where I update the changes:

```
 void janusGrid_CellEdited(object sender, ColumnActionEventArgs e)
        {
            JanusGrid.UpdateData();
            bool anyChanges = DataSet.HasChanges();
            DataSet.Tables["Components"].AcceptChanges();
        }
```

anychanges bool value has "true".

Please give me some clues, because I cannot figure out what I am missing or doing wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found the reason of such behaviour. 
All I needed was the statement "JanusGrid.UpdateData();" for CellUpdated event, not CellEdited.